# BeautifulSoup call Soup twice (.text)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, python-3.6

I am filtering a web page content which includes a table, which of I parse the row with bold text and then get the a tags there.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("https://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Weekly_activities")
data = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
dailiesunsorted = soup.findAll('tr', style="font-weight: bold;")
pvebonus = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[0]
pvpbonus = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[1]
nickitem = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[2]
nicklocation = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[3]
nickmap = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[4]

#not working when adding this line, but the line does what I want it to
nickcount = nickitem = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[2].next_sibling

pvebonus = "["+pvebonus.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(pvebonus['href'])+")"
pvpbonus = "["+pvpbonus.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(pvpbonus['href'])+")"
nickitem = "["+nickitem.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(nickitem['href'])+")"
nicklocation = "["+nicklocation.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(nicklocation['href'])+")"
nickmap = "["+nickmap.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(nickmap['href'])+")"
return pvebonus, pvpbonus, nickitem, nicklocation, nickmap, nickcount.strip()
```

The code worked perfectly and did what it was meant to do, until I added the commented line.
Now I get this error:

```
  File "/home/jens/gelbbot/gwhttp.py", line 42, in weeklies
  nickitem = "["+nickitem.text+"](https://wiki.guildwars.com"+quote(nickitem['href'])+")"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 737, in 
  __getattr__
  self.__class__.__name__, attr))
  AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

It seems I can't use the findAll('a')[2] twice, but how to fix that? .copy() doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a syntax error.

```
nickcount = nickitem = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[2].next_sibling
```

should be

```
nickcount = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[2].next_sibling
```

or

```
nickitem = dailiesunsorted[0].findAll('a')[2].next_sibling
```